# NIC missing in 70-persistent-net.rules

Tags: networking, configuration, networkcard

I am using Ubuntu and typing

```
ifconfig -a
```

shows all interfaces but one(eth4), while the file 70-persistent-net.rules contains all(including eth4) but one (eth8). Any idea why is that and what are the consequences?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the parameter `ATTR{address}==` in `70-persistent-net.rules`? This parameter is the MAC address of the NIC.

Confirm the MAC address of eth4 and eth8. The MAC address of eth4 should be there in `ATTR{address}==` in `70-persistent-net.rules` for eth4.

It may be possible as udev has a feature where it remembers NICs by their MAC address and remembers which device name they have been assigned.

Or it may be possible if you have changed hard drives and on booting the network interface didn’t come up correctly.